# nouns separated from postpositive adjectives by a comma

Tags: commas, postpositive

If *geometrical patterns* below is separated from *marked* by a comma that means *marked* refers to **the flower beds**. Is this reasoning correct? I once read something about this but I cannot seem to remember where it was or what the rule was.

> The garden, surrounded by tall fuschia hedges, had the **flower beds**
>   worked in complicated **geometrical patterns**, *marked with smooth
>   white stones*. The white cobbled paths, scarcely as wide as a rake's
>   head, wound laboriously round beds hardly larger than a big straw hat,
>   beds in the shape of stars, half-moons, triangles, and circles all
>   overgrown with a shaggy tangle of flowers run wild.

Source: My Family and Other Animals (1956) by Gerald Durrell

Comment: This is old-fashioned and over-complicated. The comma here is almost certainly just to give a pause at a reasonable place and not to adjust the sense. Nowadays, this would almost certainly be regarded as excessive whiz-deletion (by those who accept the concept) and other deletion.